# Automatically Generates files in react native android folder

Tags: react-native

I make a React-Native Application project. But in my react-native project automatically generates the following files in the android directory.

1) android/.project
2) android/app/.project
3) android/.settings
4) android/app/.classpath
5) android/app/.settings

I removed many times but it generated continuously.

I do not understand the reason behind this.
Please guide me on how to stop generating these files.

Comment: What's the problem with those folder?

Answer (score 0):

These files are system generated which helps to run and build android apk you can't  stop generating these files.